# Spring REST Security with Custom Filters and Multiple Authentication Providers - Target Method Not Called On Successful Authentication

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, authentication, filter, spring-security

I'm implementing a Spring security module for REST services. It involves 2 custom filters and 2 custom authentication providers. The application is using Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE with Spring security 4.0.0.RELEASE. No XML.
After successful authentication my custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is invoked alright. Inside the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method, I simply reconstruct the original URL and forward the request. But the request never gets to the REST service. I don't get any errors, just an empty response with status 200. I checked by removing the custom filters and the service is called alright. I just cannot figure out even after calling the success handler. why the request never makes it to the target? Please help.

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(usernamePasswordAuthProvider)
        .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .addFilterBefore(serviceRegistrationValidatingFilter,
    CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .addFilter(authFilter);
}
```

`AuthenticationEntryPoint` implementation:

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                authException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

`AuthenticationSuccessHandler` implementation:

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String path = Joiner.on("/")
                .join(request.getServletPath(), request.getPathInfo())
                .replaceAll("//", "/");
        request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
}
```

Log showing the filter chain that gets created (package names and hash codes omitted for brevity). My filters are where I want them to be.

```
INFO: Creating filter chain: AnyRequestMatcher, [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, HeaderWriterFilter, CsrfFilter, LogoutFilter, ServiceRegistrationValidatingFilter, CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, RequestCacheAwareFilter, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter, SessionManagementFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter, FilterSecurityInterceptor]
```

Comment: What does the path look like in RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler? Also what is expected to handle that path (i.e. do you have a Filter processing it, a Servlet, etc)?

Comment: @RobWinch The path, for my test, looks like /hello/asarkar. I've no other custom filters other than the ones shown above.
Please note that the request is a Spring mock Http Servlet request through a mock MVC. I'm starting to wonder if it has the capability to forward.

Comment: What is suppose to handle that URL? How is your REST service implemented?

Comment: `RestController` with `RequestMapping`. Just a few lines, really.

Comment: Please provide it :)

Comment: @RobWinch See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue turned out to be using Spring [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html). I needed to use `forwardedUrl("forwardToUrl")` for verification. The actual forward wasn't happening, as I posted above. Also `content().string("expectedString")` didn't work, content was coming as blank.

It appears that `MockMvc` is designed to test behavior, not data.

```
 mockMvc.perform(get("/form"))
     .andExpect(status().isOk())
     .andExpect(content().string("expectedString"))
     .andExpect(forwardedUrl("forwardToUrl"));
```